# Retrieving a post's 'type' field with Graph API

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

So when attempting to retrieve a posts 'type' field through the Graph API I have come across a problem.

If I use the format USERID_POSTID when retrieving the information from the Graph API it return a 'type' field for the post (status, link, video, checkin, etc).

The problem comes in if i try to query a post just by its POSTID. When sending a query this way I get all the same data EXCEPT a type field.

I have tried specifically requesting the fields when using just the POSTID and it is displeased if i ask for a type field.

So my questions are; Is it possible to get the 'type' field of a post when using just its ID as opposed to the USERID_POSTID format?

Im using the PHP SDK 3.1.1 if that makes any difference.

What really throws me off is the Graph API Explorer seems to be able to deduce the type when viewing it just by the POSTID

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it put the type when I added metadata=true in the query string, not sure why

Comment: Excellent, thank you very much. Was this something you tried on a whim, or something I was overlooking in the documentation somewhere?

Comment: compared the Get request of the Graph explorer vs. the Get request of a browser hitting the url directly, in the web developer/web console of firefox 7 (similar things in firebug, fiddler, etc)

Comment: Same issue with the PHP SDK v4, thanks so much for posting this!!